# Using Response.Redirect in the View mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am going following steps:

1. in the controller action no.1 redirect to view no1;
2. in view no.1 I want to display cshtml page and next I want to redirect to the new action no.2 by using

   ```
   @{Response.Redirect(Url.Action("CreatePdf", "Home");}
   ```

directive;

3. Action no.2 is reached and I've got my result (pdf file) but I can;t see the view no.1 from which I've called this action.
   How can I load this view and display html page?

Comment: Redirect causes the browser to load a new page, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I don't want to load new page but to trigger new action (and display current page)

Comment: You want to download a PDF to the client while still showing the page?

Comment: yes, that is what I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little tweak to @DavidG's answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(DownloadPdf, 1000);
    });
    function DownloadPdf() {
        location.href = "@Url.Action("CreatePdf", "Home")";
    }
    </script>
```

Just tested and working. It will download the file after 1sec

Answer (score 1):

A redirect causes the entire session to be directed to the new page ans loses anything you have sent out. I would use jQuery instead:

```javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(DownloadPdf, 1000);
    });

    function DownloadPdf() {
        window.location = "@Url.Action("CreatePdf", "Home")";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately now I reach view but no action occures.

Comment: Still the same, even if I double timeout.

Answer (score 0):

```
I would suggest :

public ActionResult ControllerAction1()
{
    return View();
}

For the View(), for document.ready function : 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Action2", "Controller")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: JSON.stringify(model)
    })
    .success(function(result) {
        // return true or false
        // html of json result
    })
    .error(function(xhr, status) {

    });

});
```